# PMF function: joint pmf question

Tags: statistics

For the PMF of $X$ 
$$P(X = x) = (0.5)^x \;\text{ for }\;x\in\mathbb{Z}^+,$$

would the PMF of $Y= X-1$ just be

$$P(Y = x) = (0.5)^{x-1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\Pr(Y=x) = \Pr(X-1=x) = \Pr(X=x+1) = 0.5^{x+1}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The final random variable can be express as the sum of tow random variables $X$ and $Y$ defined as:

- $P(X = x) = 0.5^x$
- $Y(Y = y) = \delta(y+1)$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac Delta distribution

The final PMF is the inverse Laplace of product of Laplace transform of $X$ and $Y$:

- $PMF = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{e^s\mathcal{L}\{0.5^x\}\}$.

So the final PMF is $P(x+1)u(t+1)$, where $u(t-a)$ is the Heaviside step function.

- $PMF = 0.5^{x+1}$ for all $x\gt-1$.

Answer (score -1):

if X is a continus random variable whith PMF f that f(x) > 0 for all x, supose that y=H(x) be a function strictly monotonous, so the PMF Y=H(x) is:
$$
g(y) = f(x)|\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}|
$$
Solving the question...
$$
\\ g(y)=x-1\\ x = y+1\\\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}=1\\g(y)=0.5^{y+1}
$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry, but this works for absolutely continuous variables only, which is not the case here.